# What does `\x1b(B` do?

Tags: python, ansi-escape

I'm a [Blessed](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blessed) user, and recently, when I tried to find out the contents of the `term.bold()` function, I got this output:
`\x1b[1m\x1b(B\x1b[m`

I understand what `\x1b[1m` and `\x1b[m` do, but what does `\x1b(B` do? I tried printing it, but it doesn't seem to do anything at all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This VT100/ANSI escape code reference](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm) should help. Hint: The `B` isn't part of the escape sequence.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Ah I see... so `\x1b(` sets the default font. So what does B stand for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The control sequence `\x1b(B` selects the default character set ASCII.  See [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html):

```
ESC ( C   Designate G0 Character Set (ISO 2022, VT100).
          Final character C for designating 94-character sets.  In this
          list, 0 , A  and B  apply to VT100 and up, the remainder to
          VT220 and up.  The VT220 character sets, together with the
          Portuguese character set are activated by the National
          Replacement Character controls.  The A  is a special case,
          since it is also activated by the VT300-control for British
          Latin-1 separately from the National Replacement Character
          controls.
    ...
            C = B  -> United States (USASCII).
```

That is provided just in case the terminal was set to some other character set, e.g., [line-drawing](https://vt100.net/docs/vt102-ug/chapter5.html#T5-15).  [Blessed](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blessed) is probably retrieving this as part of `\x1b(B\x1b[m`, e.g., in

```
    normal = tigetstr('sgr0')
```

Further reading:

- [How do I get color with VT100?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#vt100_color)
- [VT100.net](http://vt100.net/)